# Mercurial repo access order

Tags: mercurial-server

i'm facing now a new weird problem i have roles in access.conf of hgadmin repo as following:

```
read repo=a/b user=users/x 
deny repo=a/b
```

this lead to user x can't clone this repo

another roles :

```
read repo=a/b user=users/* 
deny repo=a/b
```

this lead to user x can clone repo a/b any ideas why this happens

Knowing that there is no roles preceding those roles except in both access.conf of hgadmin repo and /etc/mercurial-server/access.conf

```
init user=root/**
deny repo=hgadmin
```

any ideas why this happens ?

Thanks in advance